# if function comes across 0, do nothing in R

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
df[, -1] = apply(df[, -1], 2, function(x){x * log(x)})
```

`df` looks like:

```
sample a b  c
a2     2 1  2
a3     3 0 45
```

The problem I am having is that some of my values in `df` are 0. You cannot take the `ln(0)`. So I would like tell my program to spit out a 0 if it tries to take `ln(0)`.

Comment: One option is to add an amount less than floating point error to `x` so it won't noticeably change the results but will run fine, e.g.: `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x){x * log(x + .Machine$double.xmin)})`

Comment: "So I would like tell my program to spit out a 0 if it tries to take ln(0)." So, you want to get a wrong result from an arithmetic operation? That sounds dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifelse` here:

```
df[,-1] = apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x){ ifelse(x != 0, x*log(x), 0) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/4497050) to add a tiny amount less than the floating point error to `x`. Since `log(0.00000000000000...0000223)` is `0.0000...`, inputting `0` will work. The results of other numbers will only be changed by amounts smaller than the floating point error, meaning for practical purposes not at all.

Avoiding the iteration and using `.Machine$double.xmin` for a very, very small number,

```r
df <- data.frame(sample = c("a2", "a3"), 
                 a = 2:3, 
                 b = c(1L, 0L), 
                 c = c(2L, 45L))

df
#>   sample a b  c
#> 1     a2 2 1  2
#> 2     a3 3 0 45

df[-1] <- df[-1] * log(df[-1] + .Machine$double.xmin)

df
#>   sample        a b          c
#> 1     a2 1.386294 0   1.386294
#> 2     a3 3.295837 0 171.299812
```

To check the results, let's use another approach, changing 0 values to 1 so they're return 0:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(sample = c("a2", "a3"), 
                 a = 2:3, 
                 b = c(1L, 0), 
                 c = c(2L, 45L))

df2[df2 == 0] <- 1
df2[-1] <- df2[-1] * log(df2[-1])

df2
#>   sample        a b          c
#> 1     a2 1.386294 0   1.386294
#> 2     a3 3.295837 0 171.299812
```

Because the change is less than floating point error, the results are identical according to R:

```r
identical(df, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```